# Dockerizing java app

Tags: java, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

I'm a beginner in docker and I have one question. I have downloaded boot2docker which is running on oracle virtual box. When I did ssh on boot2docker and created a directory where I keep my simple app in java (file with code with .java extension is enough? ). How should I include that directory in Dockerfile to create the image I want and then run this app on docker?

If I manage with all of that,  should I install Java on that image right?

Comment: Search for Java on registry.hub.docker.com you will find many examples

Answer (score 0):

This article shows you step by step how to accomplish it.

https://blog.giantswarm.io/getting-started-with-java-development-on-docker/

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you will need to add or copy your Java file(s) using the Dockerfile. This is well documented on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/java/

Here's an example for a Dockerfile:

```
    FROM java:7
    COPY . /usr/src/myapp
    WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
    RUN javac Main.java
    CMD ["java", "Main"]
```

The java container is perfect for running JAR files in a microservices architecture -- if you've already built the JAR file. You can check out this example:

https://github.com/dchqinc/event-sourcing-microservices